# DropdownList: showing text instead of value in template while not editing

Tags: asp.net, drop-down-menu, detailsview

I've looked around the site, but haven't seen a question exactly set up like this.

I have a DetailsView showing employee information.  It has a DropDownList so I can select the employee's supervisor.  It stores the supervisor's ID number.  The DropDownList shows the supervisor's name when it's being edited.

My problem now is that when the DetailsView isn't being edited, the ItemTemplate only shows the supervisor's ID number.  I'd like to show the Supervisor's name.  Any tips on how to accomplish this?

```
<asp:TemplateField ID="Supervisor" HeaderText="Supervisor" SortExpression="SupervisorID">
         <EditItemTemplate>
            <asp:DropDownList ID="SupervisorID" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource3" DataTextField="Name" DataValueField="ID" SelectedValue='<%# Bind("SupervisorID") %>'>
            </asp:DropDownList>
            <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource3" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:dbConnectionString %>" SelectCommand="SELECT [ID], [LastName] + ', ' + [FirstName] AS [Name] FROM [Employees] Order by LastName, FirstName"></asp:SqlDataSource>
         </EditItemTemplate>
         <ItemTemplate >
            <asp:Label Runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("SupervisorID") %>' ID="Label1"></asp:Label>
        </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
```

Comment: Are you submitting same question again?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's just me, but I never do this kind of data access from the aspx page.  Here's how I do it from the code behind (C#):

```
        foreach (Employee x in empList)
        {
            ddlallemployees.Items.Add(new ListItem(x.FullNameE, x.EmployeeID.ToString()));
        }
```

In my case I'm putting all of my employees into an EmployeeList object, and just going through those objects, appending them to the employees dropdown list, assigning each entry's .Text to the employee's full name, and the .Value to the employee's EmployeeID.

This fills the dropdown list with readable names, but still has their associated ID (just not shown to the user).

Then when a user makes a selection, I can say ddlallemployees.SelectedItem.Value to get the ID of whoever they selected.

If you don't have a comparable system of employee objects and employeeList objects, you can still do this by just running the query with a data reader and saying while(reader.Read()) and then append each result to the dropdown list via the above code.

Answer (score 0):

Take another label of Supervisor name with EVAL function in item Template.